# privacy_info column added to BigQuery events_* table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery to query my events that are sent to firebase.
My daily query runs a union between the events_* table and the events_intraday_xxx table.

Recently, we've added integration with ad tracking framework, and my query got broken. I saw that it is because there is a new column added to the events_* table in the last days, called 'privacy_info'. This causes the union to break.

My guess is that this column is added by the tracking integration, what is the recommended way to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same scenario 3 days ago and it broke my query as well.  In order to fix it all I had to do was explicitly list all the columns I was querying for (i.e., don't do "select * from events union all select * from events_intraday").

```
with intra_prev_table as ( 
  SELECT 
  event_date, event_timestamp, event_name, event_params, event_previous_timestamp, event_value_in_usd, event_bundle_sequence_id, event_server_timestamp_offset, user_id, user_pseudo_id, privacy_info, user_properties, user_first_touch_timestamp, user_ltv, device, geo, app_info, traffic_source, stream_id, platform, event_dimensions, ecommerce, items
  FROM `analytics_XXXXXXXXXX.events_intraday_*`  
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
  event_date, event_timestamp, event_name, event_params, event_previous_timestamp, event_value_in_usd, event_bundle_sequence_id, event_server_timestamp_offset, user_id, user_pseudo_id, privacy_info, user_properties, user_first_touch_timestamp, user_ltv, device, geo, app_info, traffic_source, stream_id, platform, event_dimensions, ecommerce, items
  FROM FROM `analytics_XXXXXXXXXX.events_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = REPLACE(CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS STRING), '-', '')  
)
select * from intra_prev_table
```