# What is the "privacy_info" in events_* table bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, privacy

What is the columns in BigQuery schema:     `privacy_info.analytics_storage, privacy_info.ads_storage, privacy_info.uses_transient_token`? I can't find it in this documentaion https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512#zippy=%2Cold-export-schema. Is this the user-acceptance of the analytics/ads-tracking cookie?

[image: part of bigquery schema]

Comment: I am not sure of I understand your question correctly but are you saying that you cannot see "Privacy info" is not showing as STRUCT? I do see Privacy info mentioned in the documentation in the link you provided but I don't see the data type mentioned as RECORD. Are you asking the same question?

Comment: You may also look here if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174318/privacy-info-column-added-to-bigquery-events-table

Answer (score 0):

See the Google documentation:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Has to do with Google Consent Mode. If you have implemented this, you will see the 3 columns being filled so you can see if your users can be targeted on each level.